how do i research on the earliest historical usages (as in its applicable sense) of a certain word?
how do i research on the earliest historical usages (as in its applicable sense) of a certain word?
for example, i was reading geneology of morals in english (hackett) and there is this footnote about translation of a word.
"--- Was this what my “a priori” wished of me?
that new, immoral, at least immoralistic “‘a priori” and the, alas!"
footnote:
'The German "immoralisch" is similar to the English “unmoral”: not influenced by moral princi-
ples, not concerned with morality; N’s immoralistisch is a later formation from this
word. Accordingly unmoralische, mindestens immoralistische should probably be
translated as “immoral, at least unmoralistic.” However, this obscures the connec-
tion to N’s claim to be an immoralist, a term that must be rendered as “immoral-
ist” in English as well—the term means either one who promotes the violation of
accepted morality or one who opposes morality. '
which is just translator and editor's clarification of its meaning and reason for choosing this word.
I am actually interested in the original German text
" unmoralische, mindestens immoralistische"
in which whether " immoralistische" has some subtle references to some older texts in latin or other languages that nietzsche read,
and whether he intends some subtle nuance with "immoralistiche" which seems like a more latin and romance language based construction.
basically i want to read earlier cases where similar constructions existed in older texts that nietzsche might have based his "immoralistische" on. and how this sense develops, in German context.
i am not sure if the distinction made by Maudemarie Clark et. al on this word in german meaning "unmoral" even applies.
as both duden online and this context dictionary show that "immoralisch" seem to include the sense of "immoral" in German:
https://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/immoralisch
and
https://www.etymonline.com/word/immoral#etymonline_v_29972
etymon -wise it seems to have been coined by ciero to translate "ethics" from greek
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moralis#Latin
is it possible to find out early texts in latin or vernucular languages that try to apply or translate this earliest sense by cicero? how it was perceived, understood and employed in this sense?
and eventually when does it enter german corpus?

Please fix your punctuation and capital letters and spacing. We use formality here. :) Sometimes, smartphones are not the greatest for interacting with this site...[research x but do research on x]

For some well-researched languages there are dictionaries available documenting the first attested use of the words of that language, including the documentation of the acquisition of new senses and semantic shifts. For English, there is the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), for German there is  Grimm's Deutsches Wörterbuch.
Note that the language of philosophers is very special, and the German philosophers are infamous for the difficulty of their language. There are specialised dictionaries on philosophical language to consult ...
